# Not able to update module via drush

Tags: 7, drush

I am trying to update a module via drush. Referring [this link](http://www.drupal.gatech.edu/handbook/module-updates-drush)

```
[root@localhost d7]# drush update
The drush command 'update' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have    [error]
installed new extensions.
```

But it is giving error that 'update' command could not be found. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update all update available modules other than locked modules.

drush pm-update

or

Update specified module only.

drush up 'module-name'

Answer (score 1):

You can update your module following this procedure too:

> - make sure db is backed up
> - put site in maint mode
> - disable the module
> - remove the old module's directory in /sites/all/modules/
> - put in the new module's directory in /sites/all/modules/
> - re-enable the module
> - run update.php
> - take site out of maint mode

and if "**update**" command is not found, may be your drush is not installed properly, try inreinstalling it.